# Why was my duplicate answer deleted on the duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Moderator deleted my answer here: [How to disable ClearType in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977672/how-to-disable-cleartype-in-visual-studio-2010/12183738)

presumably because I duplicated my answer on the *duplicate question* here: [Why does Consolas in Visual Studio look bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574738/why-does-consolas-in-visual-studio-look-bold/12183639#12183639)

Actually my answer is more suited to the first question, if you read it, and I find moderator's actions annoying.  I duplicated the answer **so that the correct answer could be found**, as that question (of how to disable ClearType in VS 2010) is a particularly nasty one, and often asked (hence the number of duplicates)

If the duplicate question isn't yet merged, then my duplicate answer (which is the only correct one) should stand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, Bill deleted the wrong one - you posted one of them on a question about VS200**5**!

I've merged the other two and left your answer on the VS20**10** flavor.

Next time, just vote to close and flag rather than posting dups.

BTW: Consolas looks like ass with ClearType turned *off*.

Comment: Ha ha ha. Well thanks.